# Unable to see smoke, and still see faces of object in Wire(Maximum Draw Type)

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I am working on making a rocket in Blender using this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pQc0qIy33A

but I am unable to see my smoke effects in render mode, but I am able to see them in Solid view. Also for the cube I am using for my domain, I am still able to see the grey faces on the cube, even though I changed Maximum Draw Type to Wire.

I apologize if this is an obvious question, or if I am not describing my problem well, if you need anymore information then I would be more than happy to supply it.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Please post a blend file [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com). Most likely your material is not adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what went wrong.
to make smoke first decide your render engine Cycles or BI.

Next on the 3 screen hit space, type quick smoke

you'll get something to start with, keep in mind smoke requires light as well and settings how thick it will be can be tuned, and viewport might not reflect cycles but be just some aprouch to it.